# Cannot install R-package gdtools or ggiraph in conda after upgrading to OS X Catalina

Tags: r, macos

After upgrading to OS X Catalina and re-installing R (since OS X now have completely migrated to 64-bit), I cannot install the packages ggiraph or gdtools. I have managed to install other packages such as ggplot2 without problem, but these doesn't work for some reason. I am hoping that someone here can help me out.

1. If I try to install it in R from GitHub I get:

---

devtools::install_github('davidgohel/ggiraph')

Pop-up: 
"Install Build Tools

Building R package from source requires installation of additional build tools.

Do you want to install the additional tools now?"

But I have already install Xcode, so I don't know why I get this...

2. If I try to install it from CRAN I get:

install.packages("ggiraph")
also installing the dependencies ‘systemfonts’, ‘gdtools’, ‘uuid’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/systemfonts_0.1.1.tar.gz'

Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 24379 bytes (23 KB)

==================================================

downloaded 23 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/gdtools_0.2.1.tar.gz'

Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 32043 bytes (31 KB)

==================================================

downloaded 31 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/uuid_0.1-2.tar.gz'

Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 46706 bytes (45 KB)

==================================================

downloaded 45 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/ggiraph_0.7.0.tar.gz'

Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 372907 bytes (364 KB)

==================================================

downloaded 364 KB

- installing *source* package ‘systemfonts’ ...
- package ‘systemfonts’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
- using staged installation
  Using PKG_CFLAGS=
  Using PKG_LIBS=-lfreetype
  ./configure: line 54: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang: command not found
  ------------------------- ANTICONF ERROR ---------------------------
  Configuration failed because freetype2 was not found. Try installing:

  - deb: libfontconfig1-dev (Debian, Ubuntu, etc)
  - rpm: fontconfig-devel (Fedora, EPEL)
  - csw: fontconfig_dev (Solaris)
  - brew: freetype (OSX)
    If freetype2 is already installed, check that 'pkg-config' is in your
    PATH and PKG_CONFIG_PATH contains a freetype2.pc file. If pkg-config
    is unavailable you can set INCLUDE_DIR and LIB_DIR manually via:
    R CMD INSTALL --configure-vars='INCLUDE_DIR=... LIB_DIR=...'

ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘systemfonts’
* removing ‘/Users/USER/Anaconda3/anaconda3/lib/R/library/systemfonts’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘systemfonts’ had non-zero exit status
* installing *source* package ‘uuid’ ...
* package ‘uuid’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
* using staged installation
checking for gcc... x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/private/var/folders/fy/d14lc6rd5nq827m06zkkb1_h0000gn/T/RtmpQUHJ12/R.INSTALL29ed73b7d534/uuid':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See`config.log' for more details
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘uuid’
* removing ‘/Users/USER/Anaconda3/anaconda3/lib/R/library/uuid’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘uuid’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘systemfonts’ is not available for package ‘gdtools’
* removing ‘/Users/USER/Anaconda3/anaconda3/lib/R/library/gdtools’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘gdtools’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies ‘gdtools’, ‘uuid’ are not available for package ‘ggiraph’
* removing ‘/Users/USER/Anaconda3/anaconda3/lib/R/library/ggiraph’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘ggiraph’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/fy/d14lc6rd5nq827m06zkkb1_h0000gn/T/RtmpKdtLil/downloaded_packages’
Updating HTML index of packages in '.Library'
Making 'packages.html' ... done

---

3. If I try to install it from Terminal I get:

---

conda install -c conda-forge r-ggiraph

Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done

Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.

Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done

Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

Solving environment: \

Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.

This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.

Examining backports.functools_lru_cache:  14%|▏| 87/641 [00:00<00:00, 1400.70it/

Examining bcrypt:  14%|███                   | 88/641 [00:00<00:00, 1403.40it/s]

Examining sphinxcontrib-serializinghtml:  17%|▏| 106/641 [00:00<00:00, 1307.92it

Examining nss:  17%|████                    | 107/641 [00:00<00:00, 1310.62it/s]

Examining clangdev:  22%|████▎              | 144/641 [00:00<00:00, 1233.48it/s]

/ mparing specs that have this dependenc-...**

---

... and the list of conflicts goes on and on and on...

Any ideas?

Comment: It is normal when upgrading macOS that you have to reinstall all the developer tools to be able to build packages. So if you haven't done that since switching to Catalina, you will need to.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Joran, but I installed Xcode after installing Catalina. :(

Comment: To clarify, I have managed to install other packages after upgrading to Catalina, but these two doesn't work for some reason...

Comment: could you try to follow these instructions: https://github.com/davidgohel/gdtools#for-mac-os-users

Comment: Thanks David, but installing XQuartz didn't help. :(

Comment: Thanks again @DavidGohel for the packages. ggiraph did exactly what I wanted before I had to reinstall R after Catalina and then was unable to install ggiraph or gdtools. I have installed Xquartz, Cairo and Freestyle but it still doesn't work. I get the same error message as before. 

Perhaps the error can be solved if I "check that 'pkg-config' is in your PATH and PKG_CONFIG_PATH contains a freetype2.pc file". But which PATH does this refer to?

Comment: @klarinosaurus I am sorry, I don't have other solutions.

Comment: @DavidGohel Ok, thanks anyway. Does anyone else have any suggestions, eg. which directory PATH refers to?

Comment: I managed to install gdtools after first removing R, then reinstalling xquartz, then reinstalling gdtools from CRAN. Then I had some issues installing ggiraph but managed by following the advice here: https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/7068